# Ansible async module with poll=0 doesn't finish the task

Tags: asynchronous, ansible

First of all, I'm using `Ansible 2.0.0` (which I can't avoid).

I've a task like this. Here I'm using `ping` command to send traffic to a destination machine for 2 minutes. This command runs on a remote machine.

```
- name: Ping destination VM from host VM.
  shell: ping -n -i 0.004 100.1.1.1 -c 30000 | grep "received" | cut -d"," -f2 | xargs | cut -d" " -f1
  delegate_to: 172.25.11.207
  async: 250
  poll: 0
  register: ping_result
  failed_when: ping_result.rc != 0
```

I've 2-3 other tasks after this. That should not take more than a minute.

Now, after these tasks, I want to capture the output of `ping_result`. So I check the status of the above task like below:

```
- name: Check ping status
  async_status:
    jid: "{{ ping_result.ansible_job_id }}"
  register: job_result
  until: job_result.finished
  retries: 10
```

Now this fails with the below error:

> FAILED! => {"failed": true, "msg": "ERROR! The conditional check 'job_result.finished' failed. The error was: ERROR! error while evaluating conditional (job_result.finished): ERROR! 'dict object' has no attribute 'finished'"}

From the error, it looks like the original task has not finished. I even tried to increase the `async` time, say till 5000. No luck.

Any help on this would be appreciated.

Comment: Why do you delegate async job to other host, but check status without delegation?

Comment: The Ansible playbook runs on the test server. But the command (ping - in my case) should run on a different server. So I use "delegate_to" while running the task. Should I be using "delegate_to" while checking the status too?

Comment: @KonstantinSuvorov - can you confirm the above? Do I need to use "delegate_to" while checking the status too?

Comment: Yes, you should use `delegate_to` to check status. Haven't you already test it?!

Comment: Thanks a lot @KonstantinSuvorov. That worked!

Answer (score 2):

Answer from the comment:

> You should use `delegate_to` to check status of async job, because original `async` task has been delegated as well.

Answer (score 0):

Following worked for me

```
until: job_result.finished is defined and job_result.finished
```